# How do cryptocurrencies verify that the mining reward is initiated by the system and is valid?

Tags: javascript, blockchain, signing

I want to verify that the mining reward transaction is in fact valid and that it was initiated by the system. Currently I don't know how I would verify the identity of the system, without hard coding public and private keys, which again wouldn't be secure

Currently I'm using elliptic to generate keys and to verify them.

```
  valid() {
    if (this.from === null) {
        return true;
        }
    if (!this.signature || this.signature.length === 0) {
        console.log('No signature on this transaction!\n');
        return false;
    }
    if (typeof this.amount !== 'number' || this.amount <= 0) {
        console.log('Amount must be a positive number\n');
        return false;
    }
    const publicKey = ec.keyFromPublic(this.from, "hex");
    return publicKey.verify(this.hash(), this.signature)
}
```

Right now, if the from address is null, meaning that it was a mining reward, the transaction is automatically true. However, someone could simply give a from address of "null", and then essentially give themselves money.

How would I verify that the mining reward is correct, and coming from the system only when mining has actually been done.

Comment: what application are you referring to in this question? How does one own a 'null' address?

Comment: `and then essentially give themselves money` -- that's how bitcoin works. The miner is responsible to generate his own money in the block but it's up to everyone else to accept or reject the amount he create for himself

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how the mining rewards are paid out. In an account based model, the balance of the miner included in the header can be incremented according to the mining reward. The world state not matching would cause the block to be rejected ensuring that the system increments the balance accordingly. 
In a UTXO model, one approach would be to have the miner sign the empty transaction themselves. This would verify that they control the private key for the "to" address, however it's not really necessary. 
It all depends on the constraints of your system. In bitcoin the rule for a coinbase transaction is that it should be the first transaction in the block, and that the output utxo contains an amount that equal to the current mining reward + the fees contained in that block. The coinbase should also include the current block height as part of its data according to BIP 34. See [this](https://www.mycryptopedia.com/coinbase-transaction-explained/) for more info on coinbase transactions in Bitcoin.